# How does GridSearchCV in scikit learn pick the best parameters for k fold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running leave one out cross validation using `scikit's GridSearchCV.` After the model runs, I plot the mean train error (this is, mean for my k folds) but when I look at this graph, it doesn't give me a minimum at the `best_param_` attribute of the classifier.

Is it because `GridSearchCV` doesn't decide on the mean of the  folds  but  on each individually?

The documentation says:

> *best_params_ : dict Parameter setting that gave the best results on the hold out data.*

My code:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator= LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),param_grid=parameters, cv=loo, 
                     return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(Xr, yr)   
print('Best score for LDA:', 1-grid.best_score_) 
print('Best parameters:', grid.best_estimator_.shrinkage)
```

Say the best shrinkage I get is 0.1, when I plot `grid.cv_results_`,  shrinkage vs mean train error, the minimum is at a different value

Comment: Please provide some [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! I believe you have answered your own question but can't be sure unless we know how you implemented `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: I've updated the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be plotting the *mean train error*, but the *mean test error*. The way `GridSearchCV` selects the best parameter value is based on the error on the holdout data during the cross validation, not on the training data.

If you do this plot using mean test error, you should indeed see that the minimum will be reached for the parameter value returned by `grid.best_params_`.